# How to read characters in the detected objects rectangle?

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, object-detection

I was successful with tensorflow object detection API like an image below.

[image: tf numberplate detection]

but now I want to read character inside green box, how to do that?

Comment: You can check [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/17/opencv-ocr-and-text-recognition-with-tesseract/) and [this](https://www.learnopencv.com/deep-learning-based-text-recognition-ocr-using-tesseract-and-opencv/).

Comment: are there any methods other than OCR?

Comment: Why to reinvent the wheel. There are many anpr system.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to crop out the bounding boxes of plate(s) and then you can use [tesseract](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/). To get the text. A pseudo code for your problem may look like:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

original_img = cv2.imread("/path/to/your/img.png")

for plate in detected_plates:
     if plate.confidence > 0.98:
         b_box = plate.bounding_rect  # bounding box in [x, y, w, h]
         img_cropped = original_img[b_box[1]: b_box[1] + b_box[3], b_box[0]: b_box[0] + b_box[2]]
         print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img_cropped))
```

Comment: are there any methods other than OCR?

Comment: what are issues with using OCR? You may use a different library for the OCR purpose. but the underlying concept remains the same. The technique for converting an input image to ascii text is known as OCR>

Comment: this is the code: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60750093/8361239)

Answer (score 0):

```
# Load image using OpenCV and
# expand image dimensions to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
# i.e. a single-column array, where each item in the column has the pixel RGB value
image = cv2.imread(PATH_TO_IMAGE)
image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
image_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_rgb, axis=0)

# Perform the actual detection by running the model with the image as input
(boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
    [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
    feed_dict={image_tensor: image_expanded})

# Draw the results of the detection (aka 'visulaize the results')

vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
    image,
    np.squeeze(boxes),
    np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
    np.squeeze(scores),
    category_index,
    use_normalized_coordinates=True,
    line_thickness=1,
    min_score_thresh=0.60)

# All the results have been drawn on image. Now display the image.
cv2.imshow('Object detector', image)
```